# Can I think of this as an eigenvalue/eigenvector problem?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

**PREMISE:** Suppose you are given a matrix $S$ and you have to find a projector $P$ (which is a hermitian matrix that satisfies $P^2=P$) that is a solution of $$PSP=\lambda(S)P,$$ for $\lambda(S)$ some complex number.

**QUESTION:** Can I manipulate this expression and make it look like a conventional eigenvalue problem? By this I mean something in the form:$$M(S)Q(P)=\lambda(S)Q(P),$$ where $Q(P)$ is a column vector and $M(S)$ is a matrix. Then I would simply have to get the matrix $P$ back from the solution $Q$.

**WHAT I THOUGHT OF SO FAR:** If I think of $P$ as a `vector of rows' and write $$(PS)P_i=\lambda(S)P_i\quad\forall i,$$ where $P_i$ is the $i$-th row of $P$, it kind of looks like I'm searching for the eigenvectors of $PS$, but this is almost no progress, because $P$ is still in $PS$... Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find an eigenvector $v$ for $S$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can then take $P$ to be the projection onto the span of $v$: concretely, 
$$
P=\frac1{(v^*v)^{1/2}}\,vv^*.
$$
This works, because if $Sv=\lambda v$, then for any $x$ you have $SPx=\lambda Px$, and so $PSPx=Px$. As this holds for any $x$, you have $PSP=\lambda P$.

Comment: Oh, this is very nice! So the $P$ with highest rank would be the one projecting onto the span of all the eigenvectors with a common eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, if $S$ is hermitian. In general, it looks a little more complicated, as the geometric and algebraic multiplicities can differ.

Comment: Ok, in my case $S$ is positive. But just for curiosity, where can I find more information on the general case you were mentioning?

Comment: You just need to think in terms of the Jordan form. Just try the case $S=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. In this case the eigenvalues are both zero, does it mean I cannot find a suitable $P$? By the way, your example is relevant because I just realized that $S$ for me could have all zero eigenvalues...

Comment: There is a $P$ (for instance, $P=E_{11}$ foots the bill). But the projection "with highest rank would be the one projecting onto the span of all the eigenvectors with a common eigenvalue" is not true.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you please point me to some resources on how to find a projector that works in case $S$ is not hermitian? (By the way, what is $E_{11}$?)

Comment: Ahhh wait, did you mean that each block in the Jordan decomposition corresponds to an invariant subspace and therefore a suitable projector?

Comment: Well, the only blocks you care about are the ones corresponding to your $\lambda(S)$.